# PyQt Transparent Image Widget Background

Tags: python, background, pyqt, transparency

I want to make the background of the Widget with a transparent image, not fully transparent but the corners are round and the rest of the rounded should be transparent.
I can make the Widget-Background fully transparent with:

```
self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
```

but if i make my Image as the background it isnt shown..so the whole background is removed...

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Show the minimal working code, so that we can understand the problem.

Comment: Solved! I just use an ImageView for my picture!